# Size of the pdf file increases after removing qr code image using pdfbox library

Tags: java, pdfbox

Currently using pdfbox 2.0.24 library for removing and adding the qr code image after loading the pdf file from file system. Before removing the qr code image from the pdf file, the file size was 152mb. After removing the qr code, the file size increases to 523mb.

It was expected that after removing the qr code image, the file size should not increase, it should decrease or remain same. Also, in the removed qr image file, the qr code didn't get removed. Can you please help.

Below is the code for remove qr code image from the page:

```
pdDocument = PDDocument.load(new File(aBarcodeVO.getSourceFilePath()));
newDocument = new PDDocument();
for (int pageCount = 0; pageCount < pdDocument.getNumberOfPages(); pageCount++) {
    PDPage pdPage = newDocument.importPage(pdDocument.getPage(pageCount));
    String imgUniqueId = aBarcodeVO.getImgUniqueId().concat(String.valueOf(pageCount));
    boolean hasQRCodeOnPage = removeQRCodeImage(newDocument, pdPage, imgUniqueId);
    qRCodePageList.add(hasQRCodeOnPage);
}
if(qRCodePageList.contains(true)) {
    newDocument.save(aBarcodeVO.getDestinationFilePath(true));
}
newDocument.close();
pdDocument.close();
```

```
public static boolean removeQRCodeImage(PDDocument document, PDPage page, String imgUniqueId) throws Exception {
        String qrCodeCosName = null;
        PDResources pdResources = page.getResources();
        boolean hasQRCodeOnPage=false;
        for (COSName propertyName : pdResources.getXObjectNames()) {

            if (!pdResources.isImageXObject(propertyName)) {
                continue; 
            }
            PDXObject o;
            try {
                o = pdResources.getXObject(propertyName);
                if (o instanceof PDImageXObject) {
                    PDImageXObject pdImageXObject = (PDImageXObject) o;
                    if (pdImageXObject.getMetadata() != null) {     
                        DomXmpParser xmpParser = new DomXmpParser();
                       XMPMetadata xmpMetadata = xmpParser.parse(pdImageXObject.getMetadata().toByteArray());
                     
                       if(xmpMetadata.getDublinCoreSchema()!=null && StringUtils.isNoneBlank(xmpMetadata.getDublinCoreSchema().getTitle())&&xmpMetadata.getDublinCoreSchema().getTitle().contains("_barcodeimg_")) {
                            ((COSDictionary) pdResources.getCOSObject().getDictionaryObject(COSName.XOBJECT))
                            .removeItem(propertyName);
                           log.debug("propertyName REMOVED--"+propertyName.getName());
                            qrCodeCosName = propertyName.getName();
                            hasQRCodeOnPage=true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                log.error("Exception in removeQRCodeImage() while extracting QR image:" + e, e);
            }
        }

        PDFStreamParser parser = new PDFStreamParser(page);
        parser.parse();
        List<Object> tokens = parser.getTokens();
        log.debug("original tokens size" + tokens.size());
        List<Object> newTokens = new ArrayList<Object>();

        for (int j = 0; j < tokens.size(); j++) {
            Object token = tokens.get(j);
            if (token instanceof Operator) {
                Operator op = (Operator) token;
                // find image - remove it
                if (op.getName().equals("Do")) {
                    COSName cosName = (COSName) tokens.get(j - 1);
                    if (cosName.getName().equals(qrCodeCosName)) {
                        newTokens.remove(newTokens.size() - 1);
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }
            newTokens.add(token);
        }
        log.debug("tokens size" + newTokens.size());
        PDStream newContents = new PDStream(document);
        OutputStream out = newContents.createOutputStream();
        ContentStreamWriter writer = new ContentStreamWriter(out);
        writer.writeTokens(newTokens);
        out.close();
        page.setContents(newContents);
        return hasQRCodeOnPage;
    }
```

Comment: This most likely is a question of use or non-use of PDF object streams. Use of them allows substantially better compression of non-stream PDF material. In PDFBox 3.0 use of object streams will be active by default.

Comment: Thanks @mkl for the response, can you please help to mention where in the above code using pdfbox 2.x we can do the change in order to save the compressed pdf. have just started getting into pdfbox

Comment: I'm not sure but I doubt PDFBox 2.x is capable of saving files using object streams. (During the version 3 development phase I lost track over which features were implemented in v3 only and which features got also implemented in v2.) Maybe Tilman knows.

Comment: No, 2.0.27 cannot save to object streams