# After saving pdf file using pdfbox 3.0 alpha library, the pdf file becomes corrupted

Tags: java, pdfbox

Use case is to first remove and then add qr code image in pdf file and save it on the file system. So, first after removing the qr code image and saving the removed qr code image file on the file system, the size of the pdf got compressed which is a correct behavior. For eg, original file size was 6.8 mb and after removing using pdfbox 3.0, it got reduced to 6.7mb. Earlier, was using pdfbox 2.0.24 and 2.0.27, in both of them, after removing the qr code image, the size increases to 8.1 mb.

Now, loading the removed qr code image file from file system and adding the qr code image and saving it back again on file system. Here, after opening the modified file on the file system, all the content of the pdf file got corrupted and only the added qr code image was inserted.

The issue is occurring at the time of saving the file. Is the issue in pdfbox 3.0 library. Because earlier using 2.x, didn't got this issue but there the size of the removed qr code image increases.

Attaching the code for adding the qr code image and the error logs below.

````
   ```
   Files.copy(sourceFile.toPath(),destinationFile.toPath(),StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    pdDocument=Loader.loadPDF(destinationFile,MemoryUsageSetting.setupTempFileOnly());
        if (pdDocument.isEncrypted()) {
            pdDocument.setAllSecurityToBeRemoved(true);
        }
        int total = pdDocument.getNumberOfPages();
        PDPage page = pdDocument.getDocumentCatalog().getPages().get(0);
        PDRectangle rectangle = getRotatedMediaBox(page);

        getQRCodeImageSize(aBarcodeVO.getQrCodePixel(), Math.abs(getInchToMM(rectangle.getWidth()) * getInchToMM(rectangle.getHeight())));

        long startTimePages = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
            PDPage pdPage = pdDocument.getPage(i);
            if (i == 0 || aBarcodeVO.getDisplacementVO().isApplyForAllPages()) {

                PDRectangle pageRect = getRotatedMediaBox(pdPage);
                log.debug("pageRect width:" + pageRect.getWidth());
                log.debug("pageRect height:" + pageRect.getHeight());

                int rotation = pdPage.getRotation();
                log.debug("Page Rotation :::: " + rotation);

                PDRectangle cropBoxRect = pdPage.getCropBox();
                log.debug("cropBoxRect width:" + cropBoxRect.getWidth());
                log.debug("cropBoxRect height:" + cropBoxRect.getHeight());

                // Calculate margin between crop box rectangle and page rectangle.
                float[] margins = getCropBoxMargin(pageRect, cropBoxRect, rotation);

                if (rotation == 90 || rotation == 270) {
                    cropBoxRect = new PDRectangle(cropBoxRect.getLowerLeftY(), cropBoxRect.getLowerLeftX(),
                            cropBoxRect.getHeight(), cropBoxRect.getWidth());
                }

                float width = cropBoxRect.getWidth();
                float height = cropBoxRect.getHeight();

                log.debug("Page Width :: " + width);
                log.debug("Page Height :: " + height);

                ABarcodeDisplacementVO displacementVO = aBarcodeVO.getDisplacementVO();
                displacementVO.setPageWidth(width);
                displacementVO.setPageHeight(height);

                // Calculate llx and lly for QR Code image.
                float rectLlx = getOffsetX(displacementVO, qrImageSize) + margins[0];
                float rectLly = getOffsetY(displacementVO, qrImageSize) + margins[1];
                log.debug("Image LLX :::: " + rectLlx);
                log.debug("Image LLY :::: " + rectLly);

                BufferedImage bufferedImage = getImage();
                PDPageContentStream pageContentStream = new PDPageContentStream(pdDocument, pdPage,
                        PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND, true, true);
                PDImageXObject image = JPEGFactory.createFromImage(pdDocument, bufferedImage);

                String imgUniqueId = aBarcodeVO.getImgUniqueId().concat(String.valueOf(i));
                XMPMetadata xmp = XMPMetadata.createXMPMetadata();
                DublinCoreSchema dc = xmp.createAndAddDublinCoreSchema();
                dc.setTitle(imgUniqueId);
                XmpSerializer serializer = new XmpSerializer();
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                serializer.serialize(xmp, baos, true);
                PDMetadata metadata = new PDMetadata(pdDocument);
                metadata.importXMPMetadata(baos.toByteArray());
                image.setMetadata(metadata);

                pageContentStream.saveGraphicsState();

                if (rotation == 90) {
                    pageContentStream.transform(Matrix.getRotateInstance(Math.toRadians(rotation),
                            pdPage.getCropBox().getWidth() + pdPage.getCropBox().getLowerLeftX(), 0));
                } else if (rotation == 270) {
                    pageContentStream.transform(Matrix.getRotateInstance(Math.toRadians(rotation), 0,
                            pdPage.getCropBox().getHeight() + pdPage.getCropBox().getLowerLeftY()));
                } else if (rotation == 180) {
                    pageContentStream.transform(Matrix.getRotateInstance(Math.toRadians(rotation),
                            pdPage.getCropBox().getUpperRightX(), pdPage.getCropBox().getUpperRightY()));
                }

                pageContentStream.drawImage(image, rectLlx, rectLly, qrImageSize, qrImageSize);
                pageContentStream.restoreGraphicsState();
                pageContentStream.close();
            }
        }
        log.debug(String.format("Add bar code End for startTimePages Total Time Taken:[%d]-->Exit", System.currentTimeMillis()-startTimePages));

        long startTimeSave = System.currentTimeMillis();
        pdDocument.save(destinationFile, CompressParameters.NO_COMPRESSION);
        pdDocument.close();
````

```
   public static PDRectangle getRotatedMediaBox(PDPage page) {
               PDRectangle mediaBox = page.getMediaBox();
               int rotationAngle = page.getRotation();
               if (rotationAngle == 90 || rotationAngle == 270) {
                   return new PDRectangle(mediaBox.getLowerLeftY(), mediaBox.getLowerLeftX(), mediaBox.getHeight(),
                           mediaBox.getWidth());
               } else {
                   return mediaBox;
               }
           }
```

```
/**
         * This method returns offset X value based on given displacement. 
         * @param displacementVO
         * @param imgWidth
         * @return offset X position for image.
         */
        protected float getOffsetX(ABarcodeDisplacementVO displacementVO, float imgWidth) {
            float offsetX = 0;
            switch (Positions.valueOf(displacementVO.getPosition())) {
            case TL:
            case BL:
                offsetX = displacementVO.getLeftPt();
                break;
            case TC:
            case BC:
                offsetX = (displacementVO.getPageWidth() / 2) - (imgWidth / 2);
                break;
            case TR:
            case BR:
                offsetX = displacementVO.getPageWidth() - (imgWidth + displacementVO.getRightPt());
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            System.out.println("IMG offsetX :: "+offsetX);
            return offsetX;
        }
```

```
            
            
            /**
             * This method returns offset Y value based on given displacement.
             * @param displacementVO
             * @param imgHeight
             * @return offset Y position for image.
             */
            protected float getOffsetY(ABarcodeDisplacementVO displacementVO, float imgHeight) {
                float offsetY = 0;
                switch (Positions.valueOf(displacementVO.getPosition())) {
                case TL:
                case TC:
                case TR:
                    offsetY = displacementVO.getPageHeight() - (imgHeight + displacementVO.getTopPt());
                    break;
                case BL:
                case BC:
                case BR:
                    offsetY = displacementVO.getBottomPt();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
                System.out.println("IMG offsetY :: "+offsetY);
                return offsetY;
            }
```

Error logs::

```
08-02-2023 19:39:04.174 ←[35m[http-nio-192.168.1.3-9990-exec-4]←[0;39m ←[39mDEBUG←[0;39m c.a.common.barcode.impl.AQRCodeImpl.handleAddBarCode - handleAddBarCode(ABarcodeVO aBarcodeVO) Enter
08-02-2023 19:39:33.671 ←[35m[http-nio-192.168.1.3-9990-exec-4]←[0;39m ←[39mDEBUG←[0;39m c.a.common.barcode.impl.AQRCodeImpl.handleAddBarCode - Add bar code End for startTimeCopy Total Time Taken:[29496]-->Exit
08-02-2023 19:40:07.974 ←[35m[http-nio-192.168.1.3-9990-exec-4]←[0;39m ←[39mDEBUG←[0;39m c.a.common.barcode.impl.AQRCodeImpl.handleAddBarCode - Add bar code End for startTimeLoad Total Time Taken:[34302]-->Exit
08-02-2023 19:40:07.974 ←[35m[http-nio-192.168.1.3-9990-exec-4]←[0;39m ←[39mDEBUG←[0;39m c.a.common.barcode.impl.AQRCodeImpl.handleAddBarCode - Add bar code End for startTimeGetPages Total Time Taken:[0]-->Exit
08-02-2023 19:40:08.227 ←[35m[http-nio-192.168.1.3-9990-exec-4]←[0;39m ←[39mDEBUG←[0;39m c.a.common.barcode.impl.AQRCodeImpl.calculateQRCodeImageSize - Enter to Calculate QR code Image Size :: docSize=62376.89 ,higherSize=124740 ,lowerSize=62370, higherPxSize=85,lowerPxSize=60
08-02-2023 19:40:08.228 ←[35m[http-nio-192.168.1.3-9990-exec-4]←[0;39m ←[39mDEBUG←[0;39m c.a.common.barcode.impl.AQRCodeImpl.calculateQRCodeImageSize - Based on File Size Calculated QR Code Size :: 60.00276
08-02-2023 19:40:08.228 ←[35m[http-nio-192.168.1.3-9990-exec-4]←[0;39m ←[39mDEBUG←[0;39m c.a.common.barcode.impl.AQRCodeImpl.handleAddBarCode - Add bar code End for startTimeQRCodeImageSize Total Time Taken:[254]-->Exit
08-02-2023 19:40:08.228 ←[35m[http-nio-192.168.1.3-9990-exec-4]←[0;39m ←[39mDEBUG←[0;39m c.a.common.barcode.impl.AQRCodeImpl.handleAddBarCode - pageRect width:595.32
08-02-2023 19:40:08.230 ←[35m[http-nio-192.168.1.3-9990-exec-4]←[0;39m ←[39mDEBUG←[0;39m c.a.common.barcode.impl.AQRCodeImpl.handleAddBarCode - pageRect height:841.92
08-02-2023 19:40:08.231 ←[35m[http-nio-192.168.1.3-9990-exec-4]←[0;39m ←[39mDEBUG←[0;39m c.a.common.barcode.impl.AQRCodeImpl.handleAddBarCode - Page Rotation :::: 0
08-02-2023 19:40:08.231 ←[35m[http-nio-192.168.1.3-9990-exec-4]←[0;39m ←[39mDEBUG←[0;39m c.a.common.barcode.impl.AQRCodeImpl.handleAddBarCode - cropBoxRect width:595.32
08-02-2023 19:40:08.231 ←[35m[http-nio-192.168.1.3-9990-exec-4]←[0;39m ←[39mDEBUG←[0;39m c.a.common.barcode.impl.AQRCodeImpl.handleAddBarCode - cropBoxRect height:841.92
08-02-2023 19:40:08.231 ←[35m[http-nio-192.168.1.3-9990-exec-4]←[0;39m ←[39mDEBUG←[0;39m c.a.common.barcode.impl.AQRCodeImpl.handleAddBarCode - Page Width :: 595.32
08-02-2023 19:40:08.231 ←[35m[http-nio-192.168.1.3-9990-exec-4]←[0;39m ←[39mDEBUG←[0;39m c.a.common.barcode.impl.AQRCodeImpl.handleAddBarCode - Page Height :: 841.92
IMG offsetX :: 0.0
IMG offsetY :: 781.91724
08-02-2023 19:40:08.234 ←[35m[http-nio-192.168.1.3-9990-exec-4]←[0;39m ←[39mDEBUG←[0;39m c.a.common.barcode.impl.AQRCodeImpl.handleAddBarCode - Image LLX :::: 0.0
08-02-2023 19:40:08.235 ←[35m[http-nio-192.168.1.3-9990-exec-4]←[0;39m ←[39mDEBUG←[0;39m c.a.common.barcode.impl.AQRCodeImpl.handleAddBarCode - Image LLY :::: 781.91724
08-02-2023 19:40:10.853 ←[35m[http-nio-192.168.1.3-9990-exec-4]←[0;39m ←[39mDEBUG←[0;39m c.a.common.barcode.impl.AQRCodeImpl.handleAddBarCode - Add bar code End for startTimePages Total Time Taken:[2625]-->Exit
08-02-2023 19:40:10.854 ←[35m[http-nio-192.168.1.3-9990-exec-4]←[0;39m ←[31mWARN ←[0;39m org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.save - You are overwriting the existing file 24411393_with_barcode_img.pdf, this will produce a corrupted file if you're also reading from it
08-02-2023 19:41:02.451 ←[35m[http-nio-192.168.1.3-9990-exec-4]←[0;39m ←[31mWARN ←[0;39m o.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.BaseParser.parseDirObject - Skipped unexpected dir object = '╓■1ⁿl╘bM#L▓°MßwR╥_jΓ-G─3zyV¿╧mo■⌠»' at offset 1134626 (start offset: 1134592)
08-02-2023 19:41:02.452 ←[35m[http-nio-192.168.1.3-9990-exec-4]←[0;39m ←[31mWARN ←[0;39m o.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.BaseParser.parseCOSDictionaryNameValuePair - Bad dictionary declaration at offset 1134626
08-02-2023 19:41:02.454 ←[35m[http-nio-192.168.1.3-9990-exec-4]←[0;39m ←[31mWARN ←[0;39m o.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.COSParser.parseFileObject - Object (807:0) at offset 1130425 does not end with 'endobj' but with ''
08-02-2023 19:42:15.878 ←[35m[http-nio-192.168.1.3-9990-exec-4]←[0;39m ←[1;31mERROR←[0;39m o.a.p.io.RandomAccessInputStream.read - read() returns -1, assumed position: 0, actual position: 0
08-02-2023 19:42:15.879 ←[35m[http-nio-192.168.1.3-9990-exec-4]←[0;39m ←[1;31mERROR←[0;39m o.a.p.io.RandomAccessInputStream.read - read() returns -1, assumed position: 0, actual position: 0
08-02-2023 19:42:15.879 ←[35m[http-nio-192.168.1.3-9990-exec-4]←[0;39m ←[1;31mERROR←[0;39m o.a.p.io.RandomAccessInputStream.read - read() returns -1, assumed position: 0, actual position: -1
08-02-2023 19:42:15.882 ←[35m[http-nio-192.168.1.3-9990-exec-4]←[0;39m ←[1;31mERROR←[0;39m o.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.COSParser.parseObjectStreamObject - object stream 2145 could not be parsed due to an exception
java.io.IOException: Error: Expected a long type at offset 0, instead got ''
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.BaseParser.readLong(BaseParser.java:1292)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.BaseParser.readObjectNumber(BaseParser.java:1217)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFObjectStreamParser.privateReadObjectOffsets(PDFObjectStreamParser.java:188)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFObjectStreamParser.parseAllObjects(PDFObjectStreamParser.java:124)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.COSParser.parseObjectStreamObject(COSParser.java:773)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.COSParser.parseObjectDynamically(COSParser.java:621)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.COSParser.dereferenceCOSObject(COSParser.java:573)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSObject.getObject(COSObject.java:121)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.COSWriter.addObjectToWrite(COSWriter.java:553)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.COSWriter.visitFromDictionary(COSWriter.java:1201)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.COSWriter.visitFromDictionary(COSWriter.java:1191)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.COSWriter.visitFromDictionary(COSWriter.java:1191)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSDictionary.accept(COSDictionary.java:1258)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSObject.accept(COSObject.java:188)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.COSWriter.doWriteObject(COSWriter.java:610)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.COSWriter.doWriteObject(COSWriter.java:643)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.COSWriter.doWriteObjects(COSWriter.java:540)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.COSWriter.doWriteBody(COSWriter.java:450)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.COSWriter.visitFromDocument(COSWriter.java:1264)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSDocument.accept(COSDocument.java:402)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.COSWriter.write(COSWriter.java:1542)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.COSWriter.write(COSWriter.java:1418)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.save(PDDocument.java:1018)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.save(PDDocument.java:963)
        at com.asite.common.barcode.impl.AQRCodeImpl.handleAddBarCode(AQRCodeImpl.java:256)
        at com.asite.common.barcode.ABaseBarcode.addBarCode(ABaseBarcode.java:71)
        at com.asite.common.utility.asr.util.AsrUtil.addQRCodeForLinkFile(AsrUtil.java:236)
        at com.asite.common.utility.asr.service.AsrDelegate.applyQRCodeToLinkFiles(AsrDelegate.java:275)
        at com.asite.common.utility.asr.service.AsrService.processAndGetASRFile(AsrService.java:544)
        at com.asite.common.utility.asr.service.AsrService.processAndGetASRFile(AsrService.java:420)
        at com.asite.common.utility.asr.service.AsrService.processAndGetASRFile(AsrService.java:404)
        at com.asite.download.service.DownloadServiceUtil.downloadSingleASRDocument(DownloadServiceUtil.java:243)
        at com.asite.download.service.DownloadService.downloadSingleDoc(DownloadService.java:484)
        at com.asite.download.service.DownloadService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$fc82cf61.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:669)
        at com.asite.download.service.DownloadService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e16461c2.downloadSingleDoc(<generated>)
        at com.asite.download.rest.DownloadResources.downloadSingleDoc(DownloadResources.java:61)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:110)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at com.asite.adoddle.security.filter.SecurityFilter.processRequest(SecurityFilter.java:146)
        at com.asite.adoddle.security.filter.SecurityFilter.processFilter(SecurityFilter.java:83)
        at com.asite.adoddle.security.filter.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:83)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Try again with a snapshot build

Comment: thanks for response @TilmanHausherr. Getting error when taking build of 3.0.0-Snapshot. Error: `Could not find org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT`. There are two options, either to add qrcode image on pdf using pdfbox 3.0. alpha. Or the other one which I am trying to achieve is the size of the pdf file increases after removing the qr code image on it as [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75359435/size-of-the-pdf-file-increases-after-removing-qr-code-image-using-pdfbox-library)

Comment: Here, in 3.0 alpha, loading of document from file system is very fast as compared to 2.x. Also, the modified file is compressed after saving on file system. Performance wise there is no issue, the only issue here is our main functionality of adding qr code in pdf is not working resulting in corrupt pdf.

Comment: whereas In 2.0, the load operation was slow and also the pdf file was not compressed after saving. But the qr code image was adding fine. So, either we need to fix this issue or fix the above link shared in the comment where in 2.0, the pdf file size should be reduced  after removing the qr code image and saving on file system.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr  can you please check this case [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75359435/size-of-the-pdf-file-increases-after-removing-qr-code-image-using-pdfbox-library)

Comment: Maybe you need to use the apache repository in your pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

[PDFBox 3.0 Migration Guide](https://pdfbox.apache.org/3.0/migration.html) says:

> Don't use the source as output
>
> The input file must not be used as output for saving operations. It
> will corrupt the file and throw an exception as parts of the file are
> read the first time when saving it.

You can verify by checking out the following line from your error logs:

```
org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.save - You are overwriting the existing file 24411393_with_barcode_img.pdf, this will produce a corrupted file if you're also reading from it
```